# How to get bytes size for arbitrary array in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, cocoa, cocoa-touch

I'd like to use `let rawDataFromArray = NSData(bytes: myArray, length: ???)`, but don't know how to get the bytes length for my array. Here are some examples of what could my array be:

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
let arr2 = [1.0, 23556789000.0]
let arr3 = ["hello", "ok", ""]

func arrayLength(myArray: Array) -> Int {
    var bytes = 0
    for object in myArray {
        // not sure what to do here
    }
    return bytes
}
```

I'm not sure if going through every element of the array (and in case of strings going through every character, since emojis could have more bytes representing them) is the proper way to do it.

How to get bytes size for array?
Could anyone tell me the proper way to do it?
Or maybe it's just that it is not good practice to convert `Array` to `NSData` in Swift?

I've also seen [Converting Swift Array to NSData for persistent storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26224808/converting-swift-array-to-nsdata-for-nsuserdefaults-standarduserdefaults-persist) and [Converting array of bytes to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32528908/how-to-convert-custom-array-to-nsdata-in-swift) and [Custom Array to NSData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24196820/nsdata-from-byte-array-in-swift), but couldn't figure out how to get bytes size for such arbitrary array.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25714086/swift-use-sizeof-with-int32-array for an example that can be used for an array of integers or floats. But you cannot simply treat an array of *strings* as NSData, because the `String` structure (which has a fixed size) contains opaque pointers to the actual character storage.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR. So it looks like a bad idea to convert an array of Strings to NSData. Can you explain a little more what are opaque pointers?

Comment: `struct String` has members which are not part of the "visible" API (but you can see them in the debugger). Some of these are pointers to the actual storage used for the string. (So for example, identical strings can *share* storage.) – The point is that `struct String` is not self-contained. If you pack that into NSData, transfer it somewhere else and unpack it, it will contain invalid pointers. – Of course you *can* create NSData from an array of strings, but have to append each string (e.g. as NUL-terminated UTF-8 string) separately.

Comment: Alternatively, use NSKeyedArchiver (as in the threads that you referenced). It depends on what you want to do with the data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be a misunderstanding: For each type `T`, all instances
of `T` have the same size which can be computed as `sizeof(T)`.
In the case of arrays, there can be a *padding* between array elements,
therefore the total size needed for `arr1` is

```
arr1.count * strideof(Int)
```

(Compare e.g. [Swift: How to use sizeof?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24662864/swift-how-to-use-sizeof) for the subtle differences between `sizeof()` and `strideof()`).

Therefore a generic function to create `NSData` from an array would be

```
extension Array {
    func asData() -> NSData {
        return self.withUnsafeBufferPointer({
            NSData(bytes: $0.baseAddress, length: count * strideof(Element))
        })
    }
}
```

Using `withUnsafeBufferPointer()` guarantees that the array uses
contiguous storage for its elements.

In the case of "simple" types like `Int` and `Float` this gives the
expected results:

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3]
print(arr1.asData())
// <01000000 00000000 02000000 00000000 03000000 00000000>

let arr2 = [1.0, 23556789000.0]
print(arr2.asData())
// <00000000 0000f03f 0000204c 60f01542>
```

However, it is useless for an array of strings:

```
let arr3 = ["hello", "ok", ""]
print(arr3.asData())
// <945b2900 01000000 05000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 9a5b2900 01000000 02000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 068d2900 01000000 02000000 00000080 00000000 00000000>
```

because `struct String` contains (hidden/undocumented) pointers to the actual
character storage.

One possibility would be to append each string as a NUL-terminated
UTF-8 string:

```
let data3 = NSMutableData()
arr3.forEach { string in
    string.withCString {
        data3.appendBytes($0, length: Int(strlen($0)) + 1)
    }
}
print(data3)
// <68656c6c 6f006f6b 00f09f91 8d00>
```

Alternatively, use `NSKeyedArchiver` as in the threads that you referenced.

Comment: `strideof(T)` is `MemoryLayout<T>.stride` (as of... Swift 3?)